# Webscrape a webpage that's url same but location changes in search box in c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-mining

I have to scrape a webpage in c# and i am using Httpclient,My problem is that when i scrape a url e.g https://somethng.com/search/?query=mobile,its give me result no products found ,but when i search manually in website and give a location in search text box in webpage e.g: some city ,it shows products on page but url is same as i wanna scrape in my application https://somethng.com/search/?query=mobile,there is no location querystring in url. My question is how to handle it in webscraping? because url shows no pruducts in my app but shows products when i search manually and both urls are same.

Comment: Sounds like it runs Javascript.  You need a headless browser.

Comment: Or send its AJAX requests directly and parse their responses.

Comment: Or sends some special headers/cookies.

Comment: how can it be done? when i clicked on search ,whole page is posted back.

Comment: The first step I would take is to figure out how the web browser is handling the page loads.  I'd do this by reading the code in the page, and by watching what it loads and when.  I like to use Fiddler for the monitoring.  It will show you all of the pages being loaded, and should also allow you to look at the contents of each response.

Comment: i have no idea how to use fiddler or any other tool for this purpose :(